# "Create index" returns "rollback" of transaction

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

SqlAlchemy session was defined as:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

and was configured:

```
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
```

And need create index for jsonb field using execute raw sql into transaction:

```
with transaction.manager:
    sql = "CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING gin ((jsonb_field -> 'jsonb_key'));"
    DBSession.execute(sql)
```

SqlAlchemy log for the operation looks like that:

```
BEGIN (implicit)
INFO CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING gin ((jsonb_field -> 'jsonb_key'));
INFO  {}
INFO  ROLLBACK
```

And index is not created.

But the same SQL command into `psql` creates index without errors:

```
=> CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING gin ((jsonb_field -> 'jsonb_key'));
=> CREATE INDEX
```

How to create the index using SqlAlchemy "execute" command in this case?

Comment: This is just an educated guess - but does the leaving of the transaction context really imply commit? Maybe you need to invoke an explicit commit there? Because to me it looks as if the CREATE INDEX is actually going through, but then a rollback removes the index.

Comment: Yes, the leaving of the transaction context really imply commit. And I tried do it using transaction.begin() and transaction.commit() explicitly - the same result.

Comment: I would still be suspicious of the Zope transaction manager. But if you found a solution - good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Found one "hard" solution. If do it without using transaction and session mechanism:

```
DBSession.bind.engine.execute(sql)
```

and SqlAlchemy log:

```
INFO CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING gin ((jsonb_field -> 'jsonb_key'));
INFO {}
INFO COMMIT
```

and indexes were created into database - I've checked using `psql`.